# Adding a value of a dropdownlist to a route rather than as a querystring on a jscript submitted page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got a MVC page that contains a DropDownList

```
<form id="locations" action="@Url.Action("details", "location")">
@Html.DropDownList("id", Model.AllLocation, "SELECT LOCATION")
```

When a selection is made on the list I use JQuery to submit the form

```
  $('select').change(function(){
            var form = $('#locations');
            form.submit();
        });
```

This adds the parameter to the url as a querystring

```
http://mysite/controller/action?id=1234
```

What I would like to get is

```
http://mysite/controller/action/1234
```

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: In that case you don't need to submit the form, you just need to change the URL of `window.location.href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function(e) { 
    var val = $("select option:selected").val();
    window.location = "http://mysite/controller/action/" + val;
});
```

Comment: That errors on var val=$(e).val(); I changed it to var val= $("select option:selected").val(); and it worked.

Comment: @JohnS Ah thanks, I couldn't test it but knew it was thereabouts. Just be careful though that if you have more than one <select> on your page it will need to be edited to encompass `e`