# Pass selected value from dropdownlist as a route value in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

On a simple Asp.Net  MVC web page I have a dropdownlist. When a selection from the list is made I want to pass the selected value to the action as a route value. i.e. `http:\\mysite\mypage\selectedvalue`

My Dropdown list is

```
@Html.DropDownList("id", Model.AllLocations, "Select your Location");
```

And my javascript to submit the form is

```
 $("#id").on("change", function () {
                $("form").submit();
            })
```

How can I add this to my route?

This is a mobile site and I need to have the value in the url to accommodate anticipated back button usage.

** edited to show form**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("details", "location",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DropDownList("id", Model.AllLocations, "Select your location");
}
```

Comment: If the drop down list is in the form you don't have to do anything.

Comment: whats your form look like? Are you sure you want to submit your form and not do a GET? You need to show your action also.

Comment: may be here you can do something ... $("form").submit(); .. as this is actually posting the form.. other workaround is see post method in jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 1):

I actually had asked a similar question before.
The situation is not exactly the same but I did get it to work with some javascript.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163814/adding-a-value-of-a-dropdownlist-to-a-route-rather-than-as-a-querystring-on-a-js?rq=1)

```
   $("#id").on("change", function (e, p) {
            var val = $("#id option:selected").val();               
            var url = '@baseAddress' + '/location/details/' + val;

            window.location = url;

        })
```